# How do I do an inner select in linq?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a database table called Customers. I run the following sql to get information about the first and second customer:

```
select FirstCustomerName, SecondCustomerName, 
* from Customers where FirstCustomerName = SecondCustomerName
```

When I run this in sql it gives me what I want, so that one is ok. The problem is when I want to do the same thing in `Linq` in C#.

To achive the same thing with Linq I have tried this(still "doesn't work"):

```
   InfoAboutBothCustomers = c.customers.FirstCustomerName == c.customers.SecondCustomerName.ToString()
```

Note: InfoAboutBothCustomers is an **int** in my ViewModel

So my question basically is how do the same thing in LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what value you want in `InfoAboutBothCustomers`. Your SQL statement returns two values and you are saying that you want an int. `c.customers.FirstCustomerName == c.customers.SecondCustomerName.ToString()` will return  a boolean to say if they are equal or not.

If you want the id or ids that match you criteria, try something like:

```
var ids = from cust in customers
          where cust.FirstCustomerName == cust.SecondCustomerName
          select cust.Id;
```

Alternatively you can use what is mentioned in the other answers, which is cleaner, but just be aware that `FirstOrDefault` will return the row of data. You can then specify the column that you want by doing something like this `FirstOrDefault().Id;`

Answer (score 1):

Without sample it is difficult to provide any solution. But you can try this

```
InfoAboutBothCustomers = c.customers.Where(x=>x.FirstCustomerName == x.SecondCustomerName).FirstOrDefault()
```

In case of error /issue please share the sample.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.Where` operation

```
InfoAboutBothCustomers = c.customers.Where(c => c.FirstCustomerName == c.SecondCustomerName).FirstOrDefault();
```